# List comprehension to access a nested list within a list only in one index

Tags: python, filter, tuples, list-comprehension, nested-lists

What I need is to access an index of a nested list to filter the elements from another index in a list of tuples...
For instance I have the following sample data:

```
samples = [('waterfall03', 9)] 

distances = [('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232, 0.0])]
```

So in this case I have the sample waterfall03 where I have the number 9, which is the index to be removed from the index number 1 from the list of tuples in the list distances... i.e. I want to get a list as follows `[12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232]`

I have written the following code which is not working

```
distances = [[n for j, n, m in enumerate(zip(subarray, samples)) if j != m] for i, subarray in enumerate(distances) if i == 1]
```

**Expected output**

```
distances = [('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232])]
```

**More test cases**

```
Samples = [('highway_bost321', 0), ('mountain_0871', 2), ('opencountry_043', 4), ('opencountry_053', 5), ('opencountry_123', 6), ('palace_019', 7), ('volcano_010', 8), ('waterfall03', 9)]



 distances =  [('highway_bost321', [0.0, 10.174343253183386, 10.947746706490813, 7.187637514988234, 7.660483562939873, 10.622402335214636, 10.737785768990813, 10.566917715980832, 10.819389772897063, 12.03400784892136]), ('mountain_0871', [10.947746706490813, 0.83758544921875, 0.0, 5.838234191502578, 5.363256367154217, 1.3175048828125, 3.0810546875, 6.634500456993904, 0.78460693359375, 13.91981431878607]), ('opencountry_043', [7.660483562939873, 4.668136048210366, 5.363256367154217, 2.8142531243329643, 0.0, 5.347678752303554, 3.236628762987552, 5.377074226549635, 5.634096535101808, 13.405988675235129]), ('opencountry_053', [10.622402335214636, 0.73712158203125, 1.3175048828125, 5.876377140065916, 5.347678752303554, 0.0, 3.1134033203125, 6.11476575647307, 1.97711181640625, 13.144871284931902]), ('opencountry_123', [10.737785768990813, 3.01690673828125, 3.0810546875, 5.560564920669245, 3.236628762987552, 3.1134033203125, 0.0, 5.71620618616057, 3.09417724609375, 13.597874214619402]), ('palace_019', [10.566917715980832, 5.890665007775154, 6.634500456993904, 3.7392389463104037, 5.377074226549635, 6.11476575647307, 5.71620618616057, 0.0, 6.493675414476205, 12.731745772059295]), ('volcano_010', [10.819389772897063, 1.294677734375, 0.78460693359375, 5.709877257908828, 5.634096535101808, 1.97711181640625, 3.09417724609375, 6.493675414476205, 0.0, 13.90083238519232]), ('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232, 0.0])]
```

**Expected outputs**

```
       distances =  [('highway_bost321', [10.174343253183386, 10.947746706490813, 7.187637514988234, 7.660483562939873, 10.622402335214636, 10.737785768990813, 10.566917715980832, 10.819389772897063, 12.03400784892136]), 
    ('mountain_0871', [10.947746706490813, 0.83758544921875, 5.838234191502578, 5.363256367154217, 1.3175048828125, 3.0810546875, 6.634500456993904, 0.78460693359375, 13.91981431878607]), 
    ('opencountry_043', [7.660483562939873, 4.668136048210366, 5.363256367154217, 2.8142531243329643, 5.347678752303554, 3.236628762987552, 5.377074226549635, 5.634096535101808, 13.405988675235129]), 
    ('opencountry_053', [10.622402335214636, 0.73712158203125, 1.3175048828125, 5.876377140065916, 5.347678752303554, 3.1134033203125, 6.11476575647307, 1.97711181640625, 13.144871284931902]),
    ('opencountry_123', [10.737785768990813, 3.01690673828125, 3.0810546875, 5.560564920669245, 3.236628762987552, 3.1134033203125, 5.71620618616057, 3.09417724609375, 13.597874214619402]), 
    ('palace_019', [10.566917715980832, 5.890665007775154, 6.634500456993904, 3.7392389463104037, 5.377074226549635, 6.11476575647307, 5.71620618616057, 6.493675414476205, 12.731745772059295]), 
    ('volcano_010', [10.819389772897063, 1.294677734375, 0.78460693359375, 5.709877257908828, 5.634096535101808, 1.97711181640625, 3.09417724609375, 6.493675414476205, 13.90083238519232]),
    ('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232])]
```

Comment: this is a pretty confusing description... also, your example leaves some things unclear... do you expect `samples` to have more than one element? Same as `distances`? Why do they both only have 1 element?

Comment: This is only one case... Actually there wuill be more elements in those lists

Comment: how is it suppose to behave in those cases? Why is distances a `list`? This is going to make this inefficient. I think `distances` should actually be a `dict`... will the first element in the tuples, e.g. `'waterfall03'` be unique?

Comment: Well, @juanpa.arrivillaga...
I've edited the content with more examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you have something like the following:

```
distances = [
   ('highway_bost321', [0.0, 10.174343253183386, 10.947746706490813, 7.187637514988234, 7.660483562939873, 10.622402335214636, 10.737785768990813, 10.566917715980832, 10.819389772897063, 12.03400784892136]),
   ('mountain_0871', [10.947746706490813, 0.83758544921875, 0.0, 5.838234191502578, 5.363256367154217, 1.3175048828125, 3.0810546875, 6.634500456993904, 0.78460693359375, 13.91981431878607]),
   ('opencountry_043', [7.660483562939873, 4.668136048210366, 5.363256367154217, 2.8142531243329643, 0.0, 5.347678752303554, 3.236628762987552, 5.377074226549635, 5.634096535101808, 13.405988675235129]),
   ('opencountry_053', [10.622402335214636, 0.73712158203125, 1.3175048828125, 5.876377140065916, 5.347678752303554, 0.0, 3.1134033203125, 6.11476575647307, 1.97711181640625, 13.144871284931902]),
   ('opencountry_123', [10.737785768990813, 3.01690673828125, 3.0810546875, 5.560564920669245, 3.236628762987552, 3.1134033203125, 0.0, 5.71620618616057, 3.09417724609375, 13.597874214619402]),
   ('palace_019', [10.566917715980832, 5.890665007775154, 6.634500456993904, 3.7392389463104037, 5.377074226549635, 6.11476575647307, 5.71620618616057, 0.0, 6.493675414476205, 12.731745772059295]),
   ('volcano_010', [10.819389772897063, 1.294677734375, 0.78460693359375, 5.709877257908828, 5.634096535101808, 1.97711181640625, 3.09417724609375, 6.493675414476205, 0.0, 13.90083238519232]),
   ('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232, 0.0])
]

sample = [
     ('highway_bost321', 0),
     ('mountain_0871', 2),
     ('opencountry_043', 4),
     ('opencountry_053', 5),
     ('opencountry_123', 6),
     ('palace_019', 7),
     ('volcano_010', 8),
     ('waterfall03', 9)
]
```

then you can use something like:

```
result = [
    (k, vs[:index] + vs[index+1:]) for (key, index) in samples 
    for k, vs in distances if k == key
]
```

Which gets you:

```
[('highway_bost321', [10.174343253183386, 10.947746706490813, 7.187637514988234, 7.660483562939873, 10.622402335214636, 10.737785768990813, 10.566917715980832, 10.819389772897063, 12.03400784892136]),
 ('mountain_0871', [10.947746706490813, 0.83758544921875, 5.838234191502578, 5.363256367154217, 1.3175048828125, 3.0810546875, 6.634500456993904, 0.78460693359375, 13.91981431878607]),
 ('opencountry_043', [7.660483562939873, 4.668136048210366, 5.363256367154217, 2.8142531243329643, 5.347678752303554, 3.236628762987552, 5.377074226549635, 5.634096535101808, 13.405988675235129]),
 ('opencountry_053', [10.622402335214636, 0.73712158203125, 1.3175048828125, 5.876377140065916, 5.347678752303554, 3.1134033203125, 6.11476575647307, 1.97711181640625, 13.144871284931902]),
 ('opencountry_123', [10.737785768990813, 3.01690673828125, 3.0810546875, 5.560564920669245, 3.236628762987552, 3.1134033203125, 5.71620618616057, 3.09417724609375, 13.597874214619402]),
 ('palace_019', [10.566917715980832, 5.890665007775154, 6.634500456993904, 3.7392389463104037, 5.377074226549635, 6.11476575647307, 5.71620618616057, 6.493675414476205, 12.731745772059295]),
 ('volcano_010', [10.819389772897063, 1.294677734375, 0.78460693359375, 5.709877257908828, 5.634096535101808, 1.97711181640625, 3.09417724609375, 6.493675414476205, 13.90083238519232]),
 ('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232])]
```

But this is highly inefficient. This will be polynomial time. Notice the inner loop, `k, vs in distances if k == key` which is highly wastefull.

Instead, distances should be a dict,

```
distances = dict(distances)
```

then you can do:

```
{key: distances[key][:index] + distances[key][index+1:] for key, index in samples}
```

Comment: Using a `dict` is definitely the way to go. It's easy enough to convert back to a list of tuples if OP really needs that...

Comment: @Nick yes, indeed, it would be worth the conversion I think

Comment: My only question is whether `for key, index in sample:
    del distances[key][index]` might be more efficient than the comprehension you are using

Comment: @Nick well, it wouldn't be the same. The above one creates a new list, what you've proposed mutates an existing list, both approaches have the same time complexity, but `some_list.pop(index)` or `del some_list[index]` will be faster probably

Comment: Agreed about the mutation, but OPs question indicates that the output is in the same variable as the input... I'm just suggesting (as you agree) that `del` and `pop` would be faster than adding the two parts of the list.

Comment: @Nick right, but if that *object* is being referenced elsewhere, it may not be appropriate to mutate the lists. In either case I don't think it would make an actual difference.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. That is a valid point, it's impossible to know whether that is the case based on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your output you are re-assigned the `distances` variable, I think you can pop the element from the inner list:

```
def remove_samples_in_distances(samples, distances):
    for sample, index in samples:
        for name, list_of_distances in distances:
             if sample == name:
                 list_of_distances.pop(index)
```

running it with your test case:

```
samples = [('waterfall03', 9)] 
distances = [('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232, 0.0])]
remove_samples_in_distances(samples, distances)
print(distances == [('waterfall03', [12.03400784892136, 13.17207261956732, 13.91981431878607, 13.095577523116825, 13.405988675235129, 13.144871284931902, 13.597874214619402, 12.731745772059295, 13.90083238519232])])
# output: True
```

Comment: If mutating the list isn't a problem, I'd say this is actually cleaner, just not with the `try-except-pass`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed it, to make the code cleaner, thank